# How to test approximate equality for a specific number significant digits in Julia

Tags: julia, significant-digits, approximate

The `isapprox()` function in Julia is used to test if two numbers or arrays are approximately equal. I want to be able to test for approximate equality for any desired number of significant digits. As the code sample below demonstrates, the tolerance for approximation is either given in an absolute value, or a relative (percentage) deviation.

```
# Syntax
isapprox(a, b; atol = <absolute tolerance>, rtol = <relative tolerance>)

# Examples
# Absolute tolerance
julia> isapprox(10.0,9.9; atol = 0.1) # Tolerance of 0.1
true

# Relative tolerance
julia> isapprox(11.5,10.5; rtol = 0.1) # Rel. tolerance of 10%
true

julia> isapprox(11.4,10.5; rtol = 0.01) # Rel. tolerance of 1%
false

julia> isapprox(98.5, 99.4; rtol = 0.01) # Rel. tolerance of 1%
true
```

I read in a forum somewhere that setting `rtol = 1e-n`, where `n` is the number of significant digits will compare the significant digits. (Unfortunately, I am unable to find it again.) No matter, as the example demonstrates, this is clearly not true.

Given that we in this case want to approximate equality with two significant digits, both 11.4 and 10.5 is approximately equal to 11. However, the relative difference between the two are greater than 1%, returning the approximation `false`. However, for any number greater than 90, the approximation will be `true`. Increasing the relative tolerance tenfold to 10% will result in too low sensitivity, as the code demonstrates.

Is there a parameter/value/formula I can set `rtol` for `isapprox()` to return `true` correctly for any desired number of significant digits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick answer is **no**, there is no fixed value of `rtol` you can choose to guarantee that `isapprox(x, y; rtol=rtol)` compares values `x` and `y` to a certain number of significant figures. This is because of [how `isapprox` is implemented](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.isapprox): `rtol` is calculated relative to the *maximum* of `norm(x)` and `norm(y)`. You would have to calculate a different `rtol` for each pair of `x` and `y` you are comparing.

What it looks like you are asking for is a way to compare the values of `x` and `y` *rounded* to a certain number of significant digits (in base 10). The [`round`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.round-Tuple%7BType,%20Any%7D) method has a keyword `sigdigits` that might be of use:

```
isapproxsigfigs(a, b, precision) = round(a, sigdigits=precision) == round(b, sigdigits=precision)

isapproxsigfigs(10, 9.9, 1)  # true,  10 == 10
isapproxsigfigs(10, 9.9, 2)  # false, 10 != 9.9

isapproxsigfigs(11.4, 10.5, 1)  # true,  10 == 10
isapproxsigfigs(11.4, 10.5, 2)  # false, 11 != 10 (remember RoundingMode!)

isapproxsigfigs(11.4, 10.51, 1)  # true,  10 == 10
isapproxsigfigs(11.4, 10.51, 2)  # true,  11 == 11
isapproxsigfigs(11.4, 10.51, 3)  # false, 11.4 != 10.5
```

For the second example, remember that 10.5 is only "almost 11" if you round ties up. The default [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Rounding.RoundingMode) used by Julia is [`RoundNearest`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Rounding.RoundNearest), which rounds ties to even. If you want ties to round up, use [`RoundNearestTiesUp`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Rounding.RoundNearestTiesUp):

```
isapproxsigfigs2(a, b, precision) = 
    round(a, RoundNearestTiesUp, sigdigits=precision) == 
    round(b, RoundNearestTiesUp, sigdigits=precision)

isapproxsigfigs2(11.4, 10.5, 2)  # true, 11 == 11
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate reply! `RoundNearestTiesUp` also resolves the issue with ties above even integers gets rounded down.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just need to define your own function for this. A few tricky details:

1. What base do you care about?
2. How do you want to treat +0 and -0?
3. Numbers that straddle 0 in general?
4. Denormalized numbers?
5. Numbers near infinity?

A quick poor person's version that will probably do the right thing in most corner cases would be to do a formatting print with the desired precision for both numbers, then compare the strings.

```
using Formatting

julia> function isapproxsigfigs(a, b, precision)
         fmt = "{:.$(precision-1)e}"
         format(fmt, a) == format(fmt, b)
       end
isapproxsigfigs (generic function with 1 method)

julia> isapproxsigfigs(pi, 3.14, 3)
true

julia> isapproxsigfigs(pi, 3.14, 4)
false
```

should work for base 10, always treat positive vs negative numbers as unequal, and probably do the right thing with denormalized numbers. You may want to add explicit checking for infinities and NaN because this implementation treats infinities as equal, and worse yet NaNs as equal.

Note: Future readers may be able to just do

```
isapproxsigfigs(a, b, precision) = @sprintf("%.*e", precision, a) == @sprintf("%.*e", precision, b)
```

but Julia does not currently support `.*` precision specification in its format strings. There is a PR out for that though, so maybe v1.7 onwards will support it

Comment: What is `@snprintf`?

Comment: I am unable to find `@snprintf` in the documentation. What does it do?

Comment: I meant `@sprintf`. The `n` snuck in there reflexively from my C programming days. Also, I had an updated edit of this which somehow didn't get saved by the looks of it... Stand by...

Answer (score -1):

You can take a hint from [NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2257-L2378) and implement:

```
less_equal(x,y) = x <= y
isclose(x, y, atol, rtol) = less_equal(abs(x-y), atol + rtol * abs(y))
```

This doesn't work very well vectorized, so make sure you have a look at `allclose` if you want a vectorized version. Also, Using `rtol` makes it non commutative on `x` and `y`, so take care with that.